# Using a function inside eval() in php

Tags: php, eval

```
$answra[$j] = '$qry['.$answers[$j].']';
eval("echo stripSlashes($answra[$j]); ");
```

I have tried different methods but I cant get eval() to bring out the output. I followed a related post and got this but it didnt just work.

```
$str = "echo (stripSlashes($answra[$j])) ;" ; 
eval("?> $str <?php ");
```

Any simpler alternative?

Comment: I have no idea what you're tying to achieve here. Why do you need to use `eval`? Why isn't `echo stripSlashes($answra[$j]);` doing what you want?

Comment: write [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stripslashes.php) in lowercase maybe?

Comment: @TanuelMategi - function names in PHP  are case insensitive, I believe

Comment: you are right :O learned something new

Comment: What possible reason would you have for using `eval()` a dangerous function at best, to do what you appear to be doing!?!? `eval()` is not a good idea, its a __last resort__

Comment: @RiggsFolly people like use it to write malware with it

Comment: I just have to check - you do know you can address array elements using variables, right? echo $qry[$answers[$j]] is perfectly valid. PHP evaluates each expression within brackets before moving on to the next set of brackets, starting from the inside and working out.

Comment: @meda Oh well in that case, go ahead, lets give the guy some assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I'm assuming you have your reasons to use eval, which is discouraged, anyways, let me give you my solution)*

Okay lets we have this **wrong** example:

```
$string = "asdfg";
eval("echo stripSlashes($string); ");
```

this will not work because the used string in

```
eval("echo stripSlashes($string); ");
```

results in

```
echo stripSlashes(asdfg);
```

you can see `asdfg` is not a real string anymore.

what you need to do is to escape the variable like this:

```
eval("echo stripSlashes(\$string); ");
```

so your interpreter will know not to take the variable into account.

**TL;DR:**

this backslash should do the trick:

```
$answra[$j] = '$qry['.$answers[$j].']';
eval("echo stripSlashes(\$answra[$j]); ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes, to prevent the variable from being expanded when it's included in the string. It will be expanded by `eval` when it parses the argument.

```
eval('echo stripSlashes($answra[$j]); ');
```